# Tricky IDisposable Issue

Tags: c#, dispose

I'm trying to abstract/encapsulate the following code so all client calls don't need to repeat this code. For example, this is a call, from a view model (MVVM) to a WCF service:

```
using (var channelFactory = new WcfChannelFactory<IPrestoService>(new NetTcpBinding()))
{
    var endpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prestoServiceAddress"];
    IPrestoService prestoService = channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));    
    this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<Application>(prestoService.GetAllApplications().ToList());
}
```

My original attempt at refactoring was to do this:

```
public static class PrestoWcf
{
    public static IPrestoService PrestoService
    {
        get
        {
            using (var channelFactory = new WcfChannelFactory<IPrestoService>(new NetTcpBinding()))
            {
                var endpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prestoServiceAddress"];    
                return channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows my view models to make the call with just one line of code now:

```
this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<Application>(PrestoWcf.PrestoService.GetAllApplications().ToList());
```

However, I get an error the the `WcfChannelFactory` is already disposed. This makes sense because it really is disposed when the view model tries to use it. But, if I removing the `using`, then I'm not properly disposing of the `WcfChannelFactory`. Note, the `WcfChannelFactory` embeds itself in the `WcfClientProxy` when `CreateChannel()` is called. This is why/how the view model is trying to use it after it has been disposed.

How do I abstract this code, to keep my view model calls as simple as possible, while properly disposing `WcfChannelFactory`? I hope I explained this well enough.

**Edit - Solved!**

Based on steaks answer, this did it:

```
public static class PrestoWcf
{
    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<IPrestoService, T> func)
    {
        using (var channelFactory = new WcfChannelFactory<IPrestoService>(new NetTcpBinding()))
        {
            var endpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prestoServiceAddress"];

            IPrestoService prestoService = channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));
            return func(prestoService);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the view model call:

```
this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<Application>(PrestoWcf.Invoke(service => service.GetAllApplications()).ToList());
```

Comment: +1 for using a Func that returns your applications rather than an action with side effects!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like the following may help

```
public static void UsePrestoService(Action<IPrestoService> callback)
{
    using (var channelFactory = new WcfChannelFactory<IPrestoService>(new NetTcpBinding()))
    {
        var endpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prestoServiceAddress"];
        IPrestoService prestoService = channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress));  
        //Now you have access to the service before the channel factory is disposed.  But you don't have to worry about disposing the channel factory.
        callback(prestoService);
    }
}

UsePrestoService(service => this.Applications = new ObservableCollection<Application>(service.GetAllApplications().ToList()));
```

Side note:

I haven't used this pattern much with disposables because I haven't found too much of a need for disposables recently.  However, in theory I think I like this pattern, taking a callback that executes inside of a using block, when working with disposables for two reasons:

1. It's simple
2. It forces consumers of IDisposables to dispose of the
       instances correctly...Although I agree (I think) with the C#'s team
       to not raise compiler warnings when IDisposables aren't disposed of
       in all execution paths, it's still a bit worrisome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to use service locator pattern there? Beside it is an anti-pattern, by using `Invoke<T>` and `Func<T, TResult>`, I think there will be some confusion in the future use. Furthermore, I don't think that this way will separate the usage of service to another layer.

I think this approach, by returning the result, is having more SOC than using `Func<T, TResult>`.

```
public static class PrestoWcf
{
    public static IEnumerable<Application> PrestoService
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerable<Application> appList;
            using (var channelFactory = new WcfChannelFactory<IPrestoService>(new NetTcpBinding()))
            {
                var endpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prestoServiceAddress"];    
                appList = prestoService.GetAllApplications().ToArray(); //you can ignore the .ToArray, I just not sure whether the enumerable still keep the reference to service
            }
            return appList;
        }
    }
}
```

Cleaner, but still i don't suggest to use static method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure what you mean. The Presto service doesn't always return List<Application>. My example was just one call. If I go with your approach, then I have to create a new method for every existing method on the service.

Comment: Well, it is not stated that the service doesn't always return `List<Application>`. Furthermore, I just emphasized that the usage of `static T Invoke<T>(Func<IPrestoService, T> func)` is kinda too abstract (and for me, it is like an Service Locator). It can be maintenance hell if used in Business Layer.

Comment: Thanks, but this is all client side. It's just a helper so we don't have to repeat this same code with every call to the service.