# Does .NET have a better kind of IDisposable that the GC understands?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dispose

I have implemented `IDisposable` in a class. The `Dispose` method updates rows in a database from **in-use** to **available**. I like this non-standard use of `IDisposable` because you can use `Using`. But...

- If I forget to use `Using` (or explicitly call `Dispose`), the rows stay **in use**.
- Because the GC never calls `Dispose` for me, the rows will stay **in use** forever.
- Overriding the Finalize method is useless because, at that point, you can't reliably use the class's managed objects to talk to the database anymore.

Does .NET have something like a "Super IDisposable", where the GC guarantees to call your cleanup method just in case you forgot, *BUT where it's still safe to use the class' managed objects?*

Comment: The pattern shown here might help guarantee that the `using` is not forgetten (C# implementation): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391167/tricky-idisposable-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such "Super `IDisposable`" interface.

When someone forgets to call `Dispose` (presumably, because they forgot to enclose the object in `using`) this is a *programming error* (as opposed to a runtime error). The best you can do in this situation is log as much information as possible to let programmers know what happened, so that they could identify and fix the programming error as soon as possible.

You implement this with a `bool` flag that you set to `true` inside the `Dispose` method, and then check inside the finalizer. If the finalizer runs with the flag being set to `false`, you know that there has been no call of `Dispose`, so you log an error.

Comment: I have chosen this as the most appropriate answer because (1) indeed there is no such thing as a 'Super' IDisposable interface that does what I want, (2) creating a code pattern that emulates the behaviour I want is relatively exotic for a small team of novice coders, and (3) after much thought I agree that ultimately Dispose not being called is a coding error that is best dealt with by logging and correction. Thanks for the simple but effective tip on how to catch and log Dispose not being called!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all objects you want to use in the finalizer are not destroyed yet. You can do this by allocating a `GCHandle` that is a strong root to those objects. Or, you can root them from something else such as a static field.

Make sure that this `GCHandle` is cleaned up eventually or else you'll permanently leak some objects (and a handle).

Comment: Using this technique, can we be sure that objects internal to the database connection object also won't have been finalized? I also discovered that finalizers have max 2 seconds to complete before being killed, so if my database stuff takes any longer than that, I'm in trouble.

Comment: The GCHandle roots the entire reachable graph. Suppose it didn't: That would allow you to reach deleted or finalized objects from it. That's never possible when a root exists.; I don't consider database work a good idea inside of a finalizer. You could move that work to the thread-pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing this `IDisposable` yourself, you can make all the methods you don't want to expose private or protected, and then only expose them through wrapper methods that have an `Action<T>` as a parameter, which would just execute the action in a using block.  This pattern forces you to use the wrapper methods, which means you can't forget the `using` block.  It is clunkier and requires a bunch of boilerplate, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misconception about finalizers here: The finalizer does not have to deal with half-garbage-collected objects.

All managed objects that are accessed by the finalizer will not be garbage-collected before the finalizer runs. It works like any other method in this regard, the GC will only collect objects when they are no longer needed anywhere.

> **Reachability**
>
> One of the guidelines for finalization is that a Finalize method shouldn't touch other objects.  People sometimes incorrectly assume that this is because those other objects have already been collected.  Yet, as I have explained, the entire reachable graph from a finalizable object is promoted.
>
> The real reason for the guideline is to avoid touching objects that may have already been finalized. That's because finalization is unordered.

[Chris Brumme on finalization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx)

So you can reliably access managed objects from the finalizer, with one caveat:
The only thing that is unpredictable is the order in which the finalizers run. So if the row object and the db-connection object are both disposable, and neither of them is disposed manually, then either finalizer may run before the other; so the row-object may find the database connection already closed. But you would run into the same problems if you manually disposed the db-connection before the row. There is no way to tell the compiler that *this* object must always be disposed before *that* object.

A workaround would be to let the db-connection object keep a reference for all the row-objects, and dispose each of them in its own finalizer. That way it does not matter which finalizer runs first: if the row finalizer runs first it will still have a db-connection; if the connection finalizer runs first, it will dispose the rows. In the later case, the row finalizer needs to recognize that there is nothing left to do and simply return.

The other option is to create a new database connection inside the finalizer, instead of keeping one stored. However you need to take care: if the finalizer takes a long time to complete, and you continuously create new objects without disposing them, you may run out of memory because freeing objects takes longer than creating them.

Comment: And finalizer's have max 2 seconds to do their thing, otherwise the CLR just kills them – might not be enough time if database/network is slow, not worth the risk imho.

Comment: If one wants to be paranoid, there are other dangers as well. It's possible (and fairly trivial) to write code which, given an array which holds the only reference to an object anywhere in the universe, will cause the system to decide that the object (and any other object which is only reachable through it) should have their `Finalize` method run, but return, with the reference stored back in the array, a second before the objects' `Finalize` methods actually run.  Since such a method need not use any "unsafe" or "untrusted" code, code which receives a reference to an object...

Comment: ...has no way of knowing if the `Finalize` method could get triggered while the object is in use. I've come up with a `Finasposer` class which, given a reference to an object and an `Action` which *must not hold a direct or indirect reference to it*, will run the `Action` when the object in question *has been garbage-collected* and is *well and truly dead*. Making that work is actually surprisingly difficult, given that a "long" weak reference can be invalidated even while both it and the target still exist, but it can be done.